# BroadcastReceiver does not start

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-broadcastreceiver

i'm practicing with a Bluetooth application, actually I have finished things like, user interface, on, off, get MAC address and name of saved devices, the problem is that actually I want to find others devices, the problem  is that is actually not entering to the method:

> *private final BroadcastReceiver mReceive*

```
//buscar nuevos
public void nuevo(View v) {

    if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


        Log.d(TAG, "SE HA FINALIZADO EXITOSAMENTE LA ETAPA UNO");

    } else {

        // bluetooth is off so can't get
        Toast.makeText(this, "Active primero el bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

---

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "INICIANDO LA ETAPA DOS");

        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            txt2.append(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());

            Log.d(TAG, "ETAPA DOS FINALIZADA");
        }
    }
};
```

I'm literally hours and hours in it.

Comment: Your comment was irrelevant didn't help in anything and look like is trying to be offensive

Answer (score 0):

Where is nuevo(View v) getting called. Unless method is called, your receiver is not registered and will not work. try to register receiver in onresume().

Comment: This have an onClick from a button  in Main.xml

Answer (score 0):

I'm very dissapointed that after more than 20 hours i just have 2 answers, and no one could absolutelly reach the answer, and i keep searching until i found that the problem is in the permissions, after Android 5.0, the device need to check again the permissions in execution time , adding this line.

> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new
>   String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
>   Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 1001);

before

> bluetooth.startDiscovery();

But i'll leave it here to avoid that someone in the future loose more than 24 hours like me trying to find the problem.